# Return just the last object in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to asking on StackOverflow and to Django so I'm sorry if I made any mistakes.

So far, I have a basic API with Django and REST Framework. I want to return just the last object that was added to the database, which could be done with the highest ID.

This is the models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Humidity(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()

class Temperature(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    isFarenheit = models.BooleanField()
```

I don't have any time fields, but I can add them if necessary.

This is the serializers.py:

```
class HumiditySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Humidity
        fields = ('id', 'value')

class TemperatureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Temperature
        fields = ('id', 'value', 'isFarenheit')
```

And this is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .models import Humidity, Temperature
from .serializers import HumiditySerializer, TemperatureSerializer

class HumidityView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Humidity.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    serializer_class = HumiditySerializer

class TemperatureView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Temperature.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    serializer_class = TemperatureSerializer
```

This is the traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Subcarpetas\iot-sensors\iot-sensors-backend\iot-sensors-backend\iotSensors\iotSensors\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('api.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Subcarpetas\iot-sensors\iot-sensors-backend\iot-sensors-backend\iotSensors\api\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    router.register('humidity', views.HumidityView)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 75, in register
    basename = self.get_default_basename(viewset)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 162, in get_default_basename
    return queryset.model._meta.object_name.lower()
AttributeError: 'Humidity' object has no attribute 'model'
```

This error is only thrown when I change in the views.py from `Humidity.objects.all()` to `Humidity.objects.order_by('-id')[0]` and the same with temperature.

How do I return the last object saved?

Comment: `model.objects.order_by('-id')[0]`

Comment: for which `model` do you want the latest output?

Comment: In the views.py? It logs "AttributeError: 'Humidity' object has no attribute 'model'"

Comment: for both models

Comment: why do you want the `id` as a `string` representation of `Humidity` model?

Comment: I removed that, it was just for the admin page.

Comment: so does it work now?

Comment: No, it throws the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have `time` or `date` fields in your `model`, you may retrieve the latest object only through `id`.

```
Humidity.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
```

`-id` retrieves the objects in the *reverse* order.
Since `QueryDict` object of `django` is lazily loaded, this will only retrieve the latest value.

You can use the last function to retrieve the latest object

```
Humidity.objects.all().latest()
```

or just retrieve the object with the latest `id` by

```
Humidity.objects.latest('id')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Humidity' object has no attribute 'model'
Also, I can add time fields if its easier

Comment: for retrieving the latest value for `Humidity` model, you write `Humidity.objects.order_by('-id')[0]`

Comment: can you paste your `view` file here

Comment: `from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .models import Humidity, Temperature
from .serializers import HumiditySerializer, TemperatureSerializer
# Create your views here.

class HumidityView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Humidity.objects.order_by('id')[0]
    serializer_class = HumiditySerializer

class TemperatureView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Temperature.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    serializer_class = TemperatureSerializer`

Comment: are you sure you have saved this file before sending a request to the server? it should work now. try restarting your server.

Comment: please update the question with the traceback of the error and the new views file.

Comment: have you run the migration after adding the models?

Comment: i cannot run the migrations with `Humidity.objects.order_by('-id')[0]`it throws the same error again. But I did run it with `model.objects.all()`

Comment: After running the migration, you can change the file back to it's original state. Also you may comment a file inside view, if it causing an issue before running migrations

Comment: I ran the migrations with `Humidity.objects.all()` and it worked fine. But if I change those lines to `Humidity.objects.order_by('-id')[0]`, it won't let me, throwing the same error. It won't let me run the server either.

Comment: you don't have to run the migrations with the views. migrations are only used when you add a model or make a change to the current models, They make the necessary changes to the database schema.

Comment: The database is correct and updated with the models.

Comment: i have updated the answer. you may check it and try.

Comment: It doesn't work, however, the problem is in the `[0]` since `Humidity.objects.all().order_by('-id')` works.

Comment: Just try [:1] instead of [0]

Answer (score 0):

```
# To get last object or record

Humidity.objects.last()
```

Comment: Same error: AttributeError: 'Humidity' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: kindly do not return integer from __str__() function in your models.py. please return empty string and try.   def __str__(self): return ""

Comment: I removed that completely, I didn't really needed that. Thanks for the tip :) @kumarm5